# Почему водка "паленая"?

Tags: сленг

Поддельную недоброкачественную водку называют паленой. А откуда такое выражение? Это как-то связано с технологией ее изготовления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Палиться", "спалиться", если по словарю арго, - дать себя раскрыть, нарушать конспирацию, оказываться разоблаченным. 
"Палить" - давать улики, путь к разоблачению, подвергать риску.
Сравните "палить контору" - выдавать организацию, "малину" (место сбора) и проч.
Отсюда, видимо и "паленый" в значении "ненастоящий", "подложный", "опасный (сопряженный с риском)". Полагаю, что исходно опасность в отношении паленой водки (и любого контрафактного товара) имеется в виду для производителя, не потребителя.

//---------------

Меня гложут сомнения, уместно ли править принятый (модератором!) ответ, но тут особый случай. Я изменил своё мнение как минимум наполовину. Мне очень понравилась идея IrinaGLA. Водка действительно вполне может быть "паленая" в значении самопальная. 
Да и не только водка. Паленый = самодельный это весьма и весьма убедительно.

Есть еще несколько моих ответов, который отмечены как правильные вопреки моему мнению (даже тогдашнему), но там не все так очевидно...

Comment: А про, например, поддельный мёд или, скажем, фальшивые деньги тоже так говорят?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე - Про мед - говорят. И вообще про продукты питания. Но это ж не аргумент. Могли механически перенести слова даже не зная значения. Вот про поддельные документы, скажем, я такого не слышал.

Answer (score 6):

Палево это пожар или пожарище. Палить - сжигать. С арго это понятно.

Но водка она не просто паленая. Она была самодельная, стала самопальной, а потом уже превратилась в просто паленую.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что тут другое значение?
А ведь, правда, возможно такое...

Answer (score 3):

В словаре Даля: "Паленка, сженка, выжженный на сахаре ром, водка."  Качество, скорее всего, было не очень-то высокое. Позже стала символом некачественной водки.

Comment: >**жженка**
Напиток типа пунша, приготавливаемый из
алкоголя, фруктов и жженого сахара (точнее -
сахара, добавляемого в основную смесь путем
плавления). **Этот внешне эффектный, по
способу приготовления несложный,
неоправданно дорогой и нездоровый напиток**
получил распространение в Европе в
"золотоподкладочной" студенческой среде в
начале XIX в. и перекочевал в Россию после
Отечественной войны 1812-1814 гг. Разные
виды жженки, отличающиеся пропорциями и
количеством одних и тех же компонентов,
известны под разными собственными
названиями...
(Кулинарный словарь В.В. Похлебкина, 2002)

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно было прочитать! Я "паленку" искала, подробностей не нашла.