# Детский вопрос: кого бьет дальнобойщик?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, значение-слов, тавтология, сложные-слова

Всё началось с подбора однокоренных слов к слову "зверь":
звериный, зверюшка, *зверобой* (от бить [убивать] зверя — два корня)…

Последовал вопрос: *в слове [**дальнобойщик**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274350/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA) тоже **два** корня?*

Залезла в словообразовательный словарь А. Н. Тихонова (1990):
дальн-**о**-**б**ой-**н**(ый), см. бить **I** (слово "дальнобойщик" отсутствует).

Возникли попутные вопросы:
**1.** Какова этимология слова?
**2.** Как объяснить ребенку, что дедушка (дальнобойщик) никого не бьет?
(По детской логической цепочке: зверобой — дальнобой — дальнобойщик.)
**3.** Избыточны ли сочетания водитель-дальнобойщик, шофер-дальнобойщик?

Answer (score 3):

Википедия пишет:

> [Дальнобойщик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) (изначально) — артиллерист дальнобойной артиллерии.

Словарь русского арго говорит:

> [ДАЛЬНОБОЙЩИК](http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_2876), -а, м. 1. Шофер, работающий на дальних рейсах. 2. Человек, уезжающий на заработки на долгое время. 3. Тот, кто делает что-л. с дальним прицелом, расчетом. *А ты, я смотрю, хитрый дальнобойщик!*

Так что била артиллерия, а добавлять *водитель*- и *шофер*- желательно (так как у этого слова есть и другие значения), хотя и не обязательно (так как другие значения мало распространены). Пример:

> Двое сыновей, один уже женился, невестку в дом привел, ребенка ждут, муж ― **дальнобойщик**… [Андрей Житков. Супермаркет (2000)]

А ребенку объясните, что дальний бой — это попадание на большие расстояния, в данном случае дальние рейсы — "выстреливание", "забрасывание" товаров на большие расстояния.

А еще можете рассказать, что ударить можно и автопробегом по бездорожью. А если сможете, посмотрите старый фильм "Его звали Роберт". Там робот буквально понял предложение ударить по супу.

Answer (score 3):

Слово возникло как жаргонизм, заимствованием из артиллерийской терминологии основы прилагательного "**дальнобойный**" (дальнобойная артиллерия, орудие дальнего боя, бьющее на большие расстояния). Образованное от него существительное прижилось как удобное обозначение водителей фургонов для дальней перевозки грузов, хотя второй корень "**бой**" при словообразовании и не имел своего исходного значения и служил сохраняющим общую складность "*наполнителем*", лишь напоминая о происхождении слова. По аналогии можно приписать слову значение "**пробивающийся с грузами в дальние места**" - работа трудная и порой опасная (ответственность за груз; случаются аварии, криминальные разборки в пути и т. п.).

Из других примеров переноса военной риторики в обыденную речь можно вспомнить "**самопал/самопальный**". Изначально слово "самопал" обозначало давно забытый род стрелкового оружия, а современном языке соотв. существительное и прилагательное сначала обозначали самодельное стрелковое оружие, а затем (с оттенком некоторого пренебрежения) - любое самодельное устройство. Позже возникло производное "**палёный**", в значении (презрительно) подделки промышленного продукта. Ещё из области военной службы распространилось поучение "**учи матчасть**", фамильярный (мол все мы служили в армии) совет собеседнику в предположении его технической неосведомлённости.

Далеко не всегда из состава слова можно извлечь убедительный смысл. Вполне можно поставить и вопрос "куда движется **мобильный** телефон?" или "в чём его *подвижность*?" - в старые времена его логично назвали бы "**карманным**", в отличие от "переносных" и пр. В других языках этому телефону есть более удачные и дальновидные названия, напр. в китайском будто изначально знали о грядущем превращении "звонилки" в универсальный смартфон: там соотв. пара иероглифов буквально означает "*ручной прибор*".

Comment: А где-то можно прочитать про этимологию слова "палёный"? Очень сложно поверить в такую версию. Я слышал несколько разных версий, некоторые из которых звучали более убедительно, но и в них я не уверен.

Comment: По поводу слова "мобильный". Здесь я советую посмотреть словарь Кузнецова и подумать о том, что мобильными бывают не только телефоны.

Comment: К телефону это слово меньше всего подходит; "палёный" в уголовном жаргоне имеет другое значение, со своей, более старой этимологией, но значение "подделки" (так употребляют слово журналисты) предположительно связано с переносом его от слова "самопальный": https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: _К телефону это слово меньше всего подходит_ — вряд ли кто-то с этим согласится. За ссылку спасибо, нашёл там кроме "народной этимологии" хоть что-то, подкреплённое фактами. Вообще обидно, что на этом сайте процветает народная этимология — даже опытным участникам важно выдвинуть придуманную собственноручно гипотезу, лишь бы она казалась им непротиворечивой.

Comment: Этот термин заимствован из чужого языка, в котором (в отличие от русского) основания для такого наименования имеют реальную историческую основу: так назывался возимый в автомобиле радиотелефон (можно увидеть его в фильме Антониони Blowup /"Крупный план"/). В порядке преемственности это название сохранилось, наряду с более конкретным cell phone. В России или СССР _потребительских_ возимых радиотелефонов не было (рации у таксистов и милиции не в счёт). В бытовой технике было терминологическое деление на стационарные, _портативные_ (среднего размера, с батарейным питанием) устройства и карманные.

Answer (score 2):

> ... дальнобой — дальнобойщик.

Всё так. **Дальнобой** (дальний рейс, *жарг.*) + **-щик.**

Из словаря ***"Новые слова и значения. Словарь-справочник по материалам прессы и литературы 80-х годов"*** под ред. Е.А. Левашова, выпущенного Институтом лингвистических исследований РАН в 1997 г.:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Забойная музыка — дискотечный, с бесконечной прокруткой трек.

Забойщик — вахтенным порядком работающий в забое шахтёр.

Дальнобойщик — по типу англ. long haul truck driver — просторечное название профессии, но, поскольку у нас такой нет, слово надо считать жаргонным.

Водителей большегрузных автомобилей (грузовиков, автопоездов, фур), перевозящих грузы на дальние расстояния (многодневная вахта), дальбойщиками стали называть с середины 80-х гг. (По данным НКРЯ).

Comment: Забо́йщик — тот, кто отбивает породу в забое;  тот, кто занимается забоем скота. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/163079

Comment: УБОЙЩИК м. разг. Тот, кто производит убой (1) скота. Толковый словарь Ожегова и др. словари.